# Anti - Web Debugger

Tags: c#

Here's my code for to stop fiddler

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(URL); //Create WebRequest
     wr.Proxy = null; //This's the method to bypass missconfigured fiddler, fiddler need proxy to intercept/debug if proxy = null, can't intercept
     string html = new System.IO.StreamReader(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(); //get Html
```

That's only to stop fiddler but how about the other web debuggers? I want to hide this so I don't want them bypassing them the login.